# Trying to select last option in select. Works in jsfiddle, not in my site. Can't figure out why

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, select, refresh

I've got a select box that, basically, whenever a button is clicked, another option is added to it, which is just the value of the previous box incremented.  This is all working fine.  I want that last option selected after it is added.  For some reason though, I can't get it to work in my application, although it works fine in my jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/w5r93t3c/

The code in the jsfiddle is exactly the same as what I've got in my site, but my site doesn't select the last value.  Any idea why?

```
function addEmiss() {
        var last = $("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect option:last-child").val();
        if ($.isNumeric(last)) {
            $("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect option:last").after("<option value=" + (parseInt(last) + 1) + ">" + (parseInt(last) + 1) + "</option>");
            $("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect option:last").prop('selected', true);
        }
        else {
            $("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect option:last").after("<option value=1>1</option>");
            $("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect option:last").prop('selected', true);
        }

    }
```

Is there some sort of refresh I can call on the select to make it update?  It's a Jquery mobile site, so I'm not sure if that's related.

EDIT:  For clairty, the options ARE being added to the select.  It's just not selecting the last one like I want.

Double edit:  It seems to be something to do with my page being loaded in the DOM.  If I have addEmiss() run immediately after it is defined, it'll add one to the select, and it'll select it.  So I think if it's selected before the page is loaded, it shows up.  Just not if it's already loaded.

Comment: check if you have only one id="collectorMainsInspEmissSelect" in your HTML

Comment: have you tried to see what is the value of last issuing a console.log(last)? Does the function enter in the if loop?

Comment: @OlegYudovich, there's definitely only one.

Comment: @LelioFaieta, yup, it's printing out the last one correctly.  Like I said, it works just fine in the fiddle, so I think there's something weird with my application.

Comment: put "debugger;" inside the addEmiss. Run your code, open console on chrome and try to debug one row after another. I can't help you without whole picture

Comment: Hmm, I did that (sweet feature that I've never seen) and it seems to be executing, but nothing's changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind your click event in [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) like,

```
$(function(){
   function addEmiss(){
      .... your code
   }
   $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      addEmiss();
   });
});
```

Or try to add your script in the bottom of page.

If you already binding your button click event by using jquery then remove the `onclick` from your `button` element like,

```
<button id="button">hi</button>
```

Otherwise, it will create undefined `addEmiss()` error and your remaining code would not work.

If your are using the `onclick`, then remove the `$( "#button" ).click(function() {` from jquery code and in this case, you need to define your function `addEmiss()` before using it.

Hope, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be helping either.  And the script is in the bottom of the page. Check my edit in the OP.  The options are being added to the select succesfully, but it's just not selecting the last one.

Comment: Hope you have already added any version of jquery. Try to use jquery version 1.7.2

Comment: I'm using JQuery 2.0.3, should I roll back to 1.7.2?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should say my code is a tiny bit different from the fiddle.  I'm not using the .click(function() {  to bind, I'm just using onclick.  I'm not getting any sort of undefined error or any error at all.  It just seems like the "screen" isn't updating after it adds the options.

Comment: My suggestion, if your are using jquery then you should use `$( "#button" ).click(function() {` instead `$( "#button" ).on('click',function() {` would be better to get rid of this type of future errors.

Comment: So i added `console.log($("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect").val());` to the end of the function, and the value IS updating every time.  It's just not visually updating.  Which is what I thought was happening.